# [CODENERIX]¿Cómo transformar un objeto a su nombre real?[CODENERIX]

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, angular

Estoy usando Codenerix para actualizar un proyecto de una agenda telefónica. He añadido la sección de citas y en el apartado `Citado con:`, en mi modelo, he creado una foreign key de otra sección llamada contactos.

Paso el código para que puedan ver en mi modelo, la clase Appointment.

```
class Appointment(CodenerixModel):

    name_applicant = models.CharField(verbose_name=_(u'Descripcion de la cita'), max_length=128, null=True)
    date_appointment = models.DateField(verbose_name=_(u'Fecha de la cita'), blank=True, null=True)
    name_applicant1 = models.ForeignKey(Contact, verbose_name=_(u'Citado con'), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='citado', null=True)

    def __fields__(self, info):
        return (
            ('name_applicant', _(u'Descripcion de la cita')),
            ('name_applicant1',_(u'Citado con')),
            )

    def __searchQ__(self, info, text):
        return {
            'contains_name_applicant': models.Q(name_applicant__icontains=text),
            'contains_name_applicant1': models.Q(name_applicant1__icontains=text),
         }
```

Mi problema es que no consigo poner el nombre real de mi contacto y como se ve en la imagen inferior me sale `Contact Object(n)`

[image: Captura de pantalla de la situación actual.]

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que en el template estás pasandole el objecto tal cual y lo estás añadiendo a una etiqueta de esta manera `<span>{{object}}</span>`.

Puedes añadirle esto:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name_applicant1.contact.nombre_campo
```

Si no es de esta manera por favor, completa la información con la función que llamas y el template

Answer (score 0):

es probable que en tu modelo falte el método **__str__**.

```
def __str__(self):
    return "{} {}".format(self.name_applicant1, date_appointment)
```

Este método es suficiente dado que Codenerix se encargará de hacerlo compatible por ti (creando un alias **unicode** de tu método **str**) en versiones anteriores.